# Why does the cmd show the Windows version number as being 6.1.7601?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1.
The first line printed when I open a cmd window is:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=6.1.7601

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Why does the cmd show the Windows version number as being 6.1.7601?

What you are seeing is the version and build number (which is different to the operating system name).

For example, here are the names and version numbers of the most recent Windows operating systems. The second columns is the Version / Build / Date.

> [image]

You can find a full list at [Windows Version Numbers](http://www.gaijin.at/en/lstwinver.php).

Please note that as per the comment by [magicandre1981](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981) this list may not be accurate.

---

#### Further reading

- [Windows Confidential: Numerology of the build](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj663498.aspx) by [Raymond Chen](http://stackexchange.com/users/485903/raymond-chen) (Principal Software Design Engineer at Microsoft).
- [The Old New Thing: Practical Development Throughout the Evolution of Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321440307) by [Raymond Chen](https://superuser.com/users/174557/magicandre1981) (Principal Software Design Engineer at Microsoft).

Comment: I see. I would've thought that they would keep the build number in line with the operating system name, prefixing win 7 with a 7, and so on.

Comment: Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 are both 6.3.9600

Comment: @magicandre1981 As I understand that just means they were built from the same source version

Comment: this is correct, but Buildnumber 9200 is still wrong, it is 9600 for 8.1 and 2012R2.

Answer (score 4):

The version is correct.

Remember, the number in Windows 7 is the one that is *used in marketing*, not the actual internal version used in development.

`cmd` is showing the Windows NT version, which is 6.1 for Windows 7. The last number is, of course, the build number.